# Anonymization / Data masking for Azure Database for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, data-masking, anonymize

Is there any tools working with **Azure Database for PostgreSQL** doing Anonymization and/or doing Data Masking ?

Is there a better way that this workflow :

1- Copy production DB (from Azure Database for PostgreSQL) via pg_dump,

2- Create Docker image with postgresql,use pg_restore to restore DB, use postgresql-anonymizer (apply Data Masking Rules) and create anonymized dump.

The goal is to have a production **database dump anonymized for DEV/QA**.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't you install postgresql-anonymizer  in production?

Comment: No, I can't install posgresql extension in the Azure managed postgresql, and postgresql-anonymizer is not available (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/postgresql/concepts-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools out there that do exactly what you're looking for. My favorite is [Tonic](https://www.tonic.ai/) (full disclosure, I work there)